# Word header with chapter title

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, headers

I'd need to put in my word document header the title of my chapters, so I used the styleref field and it works, but my problem is that my chapters are named like:

```
1   Introduction
```

and I get the 1 and tab characters in my header too.
I tried to use a style on the first characters and one style in others, but it seems that one line can have only one style.

Do you guys have any idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you enter the 1 and the tab by hand ?

Comment: yes this is why it remains in the header

Comment: Well then don't do that and edit the title style to get auto numbering on it

Answer (score 0):

one line can have more than one style, just insert "Style Break": Alt+ Ctrl + Enter.

Comment: Consider adding some reference to this answer supporting what you state.

Comment: Insufficiently answered. I will not "ask you".